# Can an application override a gtk theme for one property of one widget?

Tags: c++, gtk

I'm writing a gtk application and it isn't getting along with my theme.  Specifically, the app needs to fit into a toolbar that's only 50 pixels wide, and needs to contain progress bars, but the theme has ProgressBar::min-horizontal-bar-width = 150 (this is the default).  I want to tell gtk in code that this particular widget can ignore that particular style property.

I realize I could alter my system's theme, but then the application would break if I ever did anything theme-related in the future.  I'd prefer a robust solution.

I'd also prefer a solution in which the rest of the theme is maintained, so the progressbar looks normal (except smaller).

Edit: This is gtk3

Answer (score 6):

Got it!  Thanks to @iain for pointing me in the right direction.

```
GtkCssProvider* provider = gtk_css_provider_new();
const char* css = "GtkProgressBar#small { -GtkProgressBar-min-horizontal-bar-width: 1; }";
gtk_css_provider_load_from_data(provider, css, strlen(css), NULL);
GdkDisplay *display = gdk_display_get_default ();
GdkScreen *screen = gdk_display_get_default_screen (display);
gtk_style_context_add_provider_for_screen (screen,
                       GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER (provider),
                       GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_APPLICATION);
g_object_unref (provider);
peakProgressBar.set_name("small");
```

Answer (score 5):

Yes you can. You haven't specified if you want GTk+ 2 or 3.

In 2 you do it by creating a resource in the code that only applies to a named widget. Then you can set the name of your Progress bars.

```
char *custom_theme = "style \"Custom\" { ProgressBar::min-horizontal-bar-width = 10 }\n widget \"*.GtkProgressBar.my_progress_bar\" style \"Custom\"";

. . .

// After you've initialised the gtk system
gtk_rc_parse_string (custom_theme);
```

Then whenever you create a progress bar you want to ignore the theme, call

```
gtk_widget_set_name (progress_bar, "my_progress_bar");
```

and it should get the custom style applied to it.

The theme system is tricky to get the paths correct, so some fiddling might be required.

The documentation for the Resource files are here: http://developer.gnome.org/gtk2/stable/gtk2-Resource-Files.html

However, all this has been deprecated for GTK+ 3, although it should still work, the correct way to do it is with CSS styles which are described here: http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkCssProvider.html but I have to admit I'm not sure how they work, although I presume it's something similar but with a CSS-like syntax instead

Comment: I'm using gtk3.  I think I translated this into GtkCssProvider.  It compiles and runs but it doesn't work.  Are you sure there isn't some step where I tell gtk to actually use the style I've created?

Comment: Glad I could help in a small way

Answer (score 2):

thanks, this was very useful for me too.

for one widget instead of adding to the screen the
functions
gtk_widget_get_style_context()
and
gtk_style_context_add_provider()
can be used... like this:

```
void style_to_widget(GtkWidget * w, GtkStyleProvider * s)
{
    gtk_style_context_add_provider(gtk_widget_get_style_context(w),
                                   s, GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_APPLICATION);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Gtk (and Gtkmm) uses CSS for this purpose.
What I explain below is setting up your program to use an external CSS file, as compared to the existing answers which relate to coding it inside the .cpp file.

## Preparing For Custom CSS

You first need to create a [CssProvider](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/stable/classGtk_1_1CssProvider.html#details), a [Style Context](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/stable/classGtk_1_1StyleContext.html#details), and a [Screen](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/stable/classGdk_1_1Screen.html#details).

These three objects need to be within the main loop, before you **Run** the program.

```
// Create CssProvider
Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::CssProvider> cssProvider = Gtk::CssProvider::create();
cssProvider->load_from_path("relative or absolute path to YourTheme.css");

// Create StyleContext
Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::StyleContext> styleContext = Gtk::StyleContext::create();

//get default screen
Glib::RefPtr<Gdk::Screen> screen = Gdk::Screen::get_default();

//add provider for screen in all application
styleContext->add_provider_for_screen(screen, cssProvider, GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_APPLICATION);
```

## Using CSS

Because the documentation is sub-par on Gtkmm, it's easier to use the Gtk+ documentation in order to find the "class" or "style" names of the widgets.
Alternatively, you can find existing themes and open their CSS files to find the names ('/usr/share/themes/').

Gtk/mm follows similar selectors to normal CSS.

The following are an extract of the full list which you can find [here](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/chap-css-overview.html) (Despite being labelled as GTK+, it applies to all wrappers, including Gtkmm).

`*` Any node.
`E` Any node with name "E".
`E.class` Any E node with the given style class.
`E#id#` Any E node with the given ID. (GTK uses the widget name as ID).
`E:nth-child` Any E node which is the n-th child of its parent node.
`E:active, E:hover, E:focus` Any E node which is part of a widget with the corresponding state.
`E>F`  Any F node which is a child of an E node.

### Example:

The following is an example extract of the CSS I use for one of my own programs.

```css
.background{
 background-color: @shade0;
 color: @mainTextColour;
}

#EngineTabSidePanel > GtkGrid{

 background-color: @shade1;
}

/* BUTTONS:*/
.button{
 border: none;
 border-radius: 0;
 background-color: @shade1;
 color: rgb(175, 175, 175);
}

.button:insensitive{
 background-color: @shade0;
 color: rgb(150, 150, 150);
}

.button:hover {
 background-color: @shade2;
}

.button:active{
 background-color: @shade1;
}


.stack-switcher .button{
 border-bottom: 3.5px solid @primary_4;
}

.stack-switcher .button:checked,
.stack-switcher .button:active{
 background-color: @shade2;
 border-bottom: 7.5px solid @primary_0;
}

.stack-switcher .requires-attention{
 border-bottom: 7.5px solid @altprimary_0;
}
```

---

## Gotchas & Additional Links:

- If your CSS file contains any syntax errors, the program *will not run*.
- The ID/Class names can be confused for each other.  For example, there is a '.progressbar' and a 'GtkProgressBar'
- [An index page](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/theming.html) relating to theming in Gtk.
- [A page](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/chap-css-overview.html) specific to GTK CSS.